# How can I use twitter bootstrap popover with angularjs directly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

For example i have this files

```
<!-- index.tpl.html -->
<span ng-repeat="d in data" ng-controller="clickMe">
    <a href="#" class="click-me" data-data="{{d.data}}">{{d.id}}</a>
</span>
```

.

```
<!-- popover.tpl.html -->
<form>
<div ng-switch="data.option">
    <div ng-swith-when="one">One</div>
    <div ng-swith-when="two">Two</div>
    <div ng-swith-when="three">Three</div>
</div>
</form>
```

This JS code

```
 angular.module("myApp").controller("clickMe", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.data = [
        {id: 1, data: {option: 'one'}},
        {id: 2, data: {option: 'two'}},
        {id: 3, data: {option: 'three'}},
    ];
}]);
```

And also I have event

```
$(document).on("click", ".click-me", function(){
    $(this).popover({
         title: "Click Me",
         content: "/** How can I render template `popover.tpl.html there?` **/"
    });
});
```

I tried to use directives, but also nothing working. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: look into angular-bootstrap

Comment: although there are better directive's as already mentioned, general rule of thumb for plugins is initialize in a directive

Answer (score 2):

[Angular-Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) Is the best way to accomplish what you're looking for.